# Add the Apollo React onError from apollo-link-error to the link const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, apollo

I want to add `onError` to my `index.js` Apollo file. So that [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bv74TcKb1jw) helped me how a very basic example looks like. But as I have some more links in my project, it's a bit different to what is shown there.

Index.js:

```
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context'
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws'
import { split } from 'apollo-link'
import { onError } from "apollo-link-error";
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000',
})

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    },
  }
})

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `ws://localhost:4000`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: {
      authToken: localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN),
    },
  },
})

const link = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query)
    return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription'
  },
  wsLink,
  authLink.concat(httpLink),
)

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```

Now I want to add the `errorLink` to my project to track error with this code:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, location, path }) =>
      console.log(`[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${location}, Path: ${path}`),
    );

 if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
});
```

But I'm not sure how to add that new link to the `link` const. Is it done with a `concat` or something else?

I already had a look on the [composing links](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/composition/) section. But that's also too different from my example.

Comment: Does `link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, ...link])` not work for you? (Put this when instantiating a new `ApolloClient`)

Comment: That gives me `TypeError: link is not iterable`.

Comment: Ah, I think [`split`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/blob/master/packages/apollo-link/src/link.ts#L41) is returning a new `ApolloLink`. In this case, `link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, link])` should work.

Comment: Great that works. Now I can see the message in the logs. But I would like to deny that the User can see that error on full details in the Browser. Maybe I was expecting something wrong from the onError, but isn't it possible to only let the User get a popup with the error message or something like that? How would be the best way to do that? I know it's a new question tho =)

Comment: No problem, I will just use that comment as an answer for now. For your other question,I think you probably don't need an errorLink. Have you looked into [`errorPolicy`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/) yet?

Comment: I was on that site already. But not quite sure how that helps me. Maybe it helps you to know that I want to catch errors from an async function.

Comment: If you set `errorPolicy: 'all'` in your `useQuery` hook, any error thrown during the graphql operation should be available in the `error` object returned from the hook. If that doesn't help, maybe you can open up a new question with more details so we can take a look.

Comment: That errorPolicy does not help. Yes when my issue still exists. I gonna open a new question. Thanks for the fast help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`split`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/blob/master/packages/apollo-link/src/link.ts#L41) is returning a new `ApolloLink`.

In this case, doing `link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, link])` should work. It will create a new `ApolloLink` from an array of `ApolloLink`.

Answer (score 0):

As I also wanted to **not** let the user run into an **error message**. This is one method that **prevents** the frontend from **showing** the **error**:

```
const defaultOptions = { 
  query: {
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  },
  mutate: {
    errorPolicy: 'all'
  }
}

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([errorLink, link]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions,
})
```